# Needing help using DATEADD to only display column dates after current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, dateadd

currently writing a query to pull employee anniversary dates. so far i am able to pull the dates for 5, 10, 15 and 25 years but i am trying to only pull anniversary dates after the current date for each. any ideas?

```
SELECT
    HireDate, 
    DATEADD(year, 5, HireDate)  AS '5_Year_Anniversary',
    DATEADD(year, 10, HireDate) AS '10_Year_Anniversary',
    DATEADD(year, 15, HireDate) AS '15_Year_Anniversary',
    DATEADD(year, 25, HireDate) AS '25_Year_Anniversary'
FROM
    EMPTABLE;
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: So if an employee has already worked there for more than 5 years, what should the 5_Year_Anniversary column display?  `NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    HireDate, 
    case when DATEADD(year, 5, HireDate) >= getdate() --check to see if the anniversary is on or after the current date
         then DATEADD(year, 5, HireDate) 
         else NULL end  AS '5_Year_Anniversary' --etc, repeat for your other columns
FROM
    EMPTABLE
where DATEADD(year, 25, HireDate) >= getdate() --to filter out employees where all anniversary columns would be NULL
```

Using a case statement like above should work, depending on what value you want to display for these columns when the employee has already passed their anniversary.  You may need to `cast`/`convert` your anniversary date if you want a specific value in those cases.

For example:

```
SELECT
    HireDate, 
    case when DATEADD(year, 5, HireDate) >= getdate() --check to see if the anniversary is on or after the current date
         then cast(DATEADD(year, 5, HireDate)  as varchar(20))
         else 'Already Passed' end  AS '5_Year_Anniversary' --etc, repeat for your other columns
FROM
    EMPTABLE
where DATEADD(year, 25, HireDate) >= getdate() --to filter out employees where all anniversary columns would be NULL
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that is exactly what i needed! i thought it might have something to do with a CASE statement but was having a time with it

Answer (score 0):

Compare each anniversary and only show if anniversary date is after current date.

The SELECT statement is the solution. Field will return NULL if date has passed.

```
CREATE TABLE #EMPTABLE
(
    HireDate datetime
)
GO

INSERT INTO #EMPTABLE
VALUES
    ('2018-01-01'),
    ('2013-01-01'),
    ('2008-01-01'),
    ('2003-01-01'),
    ('1993-01-01')
GO


SELECT
    GETDATE() [Current Date],
    HireDate, 
    CASE WHEN ( DATEADD(year, 5, HireDate) > GETDATE() )
        THEN DATEADD(year, 5, HireDate)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS [5_Year_Anniversary],
    CASE WHEN ( DATEADD(year, 10, HireDate) > GETDATE() )
        THEN DATEADD(year, 10, HireDate)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS [10_Year_Anniversary],
    CASE WHEN ( DATEADD(year, 15, HireDate) > GETDATE() )
        THEN DATEADD(year, 15, HireDate)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS [15_Year_Anniversary],
    CASE WHEN ( DATEADD(year, 25, HireDate) > GETDATE() )
        THEN DATEADD(year, 25, HireDate)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS [25_Year_Anniversary]
FROM
    #EMPTABLE
GO
```